# php fetch column values from database and display in html table column

Tags: php, mysql, sql, html

I have a table in database name `Accounts` in which i have many rows and many columns, i want to show a column `Account` (all values) in my html table. I have tried many method to show a specific column values without using index in html using `php` and I am using `MySql`.

```
$storeArray = Array();
while($rowval = mysql_fetch_array($whole, MYSQL_ASSOC))
{ 
$storeArray[] =  $rowval['Account'];  
$status= $rowval['status'];
$ph1= $rowval['Phone1'];
$ph2= $rowval['Phone2'];
}
```

by using `<?php echo  $storeArray[0]; ?>` and `<?php echo  $storeArray[1]; ?>` in `<td>` i got the solution. My question is there any way, it automatically show all values without providing any `index`?

Comment: Even a simple search on this site would have turned out hundreds of examples...

Comment: please show your code

Comment: edited, please check this out and help me out.

Comment: you can extract  $rowval so that you can use table field name as variable name like $Account

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$conn=new mysqli("localhost","root","","your_db");

$rows=$conn->query("select username from User");

echo "<table border='1'>";
echo "<tr><th>Username</th></tr>";
while(list($username)=$rows->fetch_row()){
  echo "<tr><td>$username</td></tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
```

Comment: Thanks, can you tell me is there any way if click on `$username` then it fetch the whole row related to that username?

Answer (score 1):

This is a pretty elaborate question. I think the best I can do is point you in the right direction. There is a good tutorial for this on w3schools.com. You should at least read these:

[PHP - Connect to MySQL](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_connect.asp)

[PHP - Select Data From MySQL](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_select.asp)

and maybe

[PHP - Limit Data Selections From MySQL](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_select_limit.asp)

Comment: Thanks for your help. without giving index means automatically takes all the values from `Accounts` column and display in my html table

Answer (score 1):

```
**file user.php**
<?php
$conn=new mysqli("localhost","root","","your_db");

$rows=$conn->query("select id,username from User");

echo "<table border='1'>";
echo "<tr><th>Username</th></tr>";
while(list($id,$username)=$rows->fetch_row()){
  echo "<tr>";
  echo "<td>";
  echo "<form action='user_details.php' target='_blank' method='post'>";
  echo "<input type='hidden' name='txtId' value='$id' />";
  echo "$id - $username";
  echo "<input type='submit' name='btnView' value='View' />";
  echo "</form>";
  echo "</td>";
  echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
?>

**file user_details.php**
<?php 

 if(isset($_POST["btnView"])){

   $id=$_POST["txtId"];

   $conn=new mysqli("localhost","root","","your_db");

   $row=$conn->query("select id,username,email,phone from User where id='$id'");

   list($id,$username,$email,$phone)=$row->fetch_row();

   echo $id," ",$username," ",$email," ",$phone;

 }



?>
```

Comment: Thanks.
http://imgur.com/6QsvYrK
Here is the link of image, I want whenever user click on name its details shows in above boxes, the details are associated to that specific name which is clicked.

Comment: If you want to a show the details above of the name list then include the user_details.php file at the top of user.php

Answer (score 1):

if you want to fetch more than one database column in your html table column.

```
$conn=new mysqli("localhost","root","","your_db");

$rows=$conn->query("select col1,col2 from Tablename");

echo "<table border='1'>";
echo "<tr><th>col1</th><th>col2</th></tr>";
while(list($col1, $col2)=$rows->fetch_row())
{
  echo "<tr><td>$col1</td><td>$col2</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
```